How can I make a while loop wait for a JButton to be pressed?
I am very new to Java, and am trying to make a program that asks to use to guess a random number between 1 and 77. How can I make the while loop in this code run only when an answer has been provided in the JField, and the button has been pressed? Right now this program just skips the while loop altogether when run and just displays the losing message.
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;

public class NumberGame {
    private static int guess = 0;
    
    private static int presses = 0;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame window = new JFrame("Number Game");
        window.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        
        JPanel topPanel = new JPanel();
        JPanel bottomPanel = new JPanel();
        JPanel centerPanel = new JPanel();
        
        JLabel topLabel = new JLabel("Pick numbers from 1 to 77.");
        topPanel.add(topLabel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        
        JTextField field = new JTextField(10);
        field.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(80,20));
        topPanel.add(field, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        
        JButton button = new JButton("Guess");
        button.addActionListener(e -> {
            if (field.getText() != "") {
                guess = Integer.parseInt(field.getText());
                field.setText("");
                presses ++;
            }
        });
        button.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100,40));
        centerPanel.add(button, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        
        JLabel bottomLabel = new JLabel("Enter your guess");
        bottomPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        bottomPanel.add(bottomLabel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        
        //Generate a random number using the math class
        int num = (int)(77*Math.random())+1;
        //System.out.println(num);
        
        int guesses = 5;
        
        guess = -1;
        presses = 0;
        
        window.add(topPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        window.add(bottomPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        window.add(centerPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        window.setSize(300,200);
        window.setVisible(true);
        
        while (guess != num && guesses > 0 && presses == (5-guesses)) {
            if (guess > num && guess != -1) {
                bottomLabel.setText("Skill issue, too big. Try again. ");
            }else if (guess < num  && guess != -1){
                bottomLabel.setText("Ha ha, too small. Try again. ");
            }
            guesses --;
            presses ++;
        }
        
        if (guesses > 0) {
            bottomLabel.setText("GG! You won! You had " + guesses + " guesses remaining.");
        }else {
            bottomLabel.setText("lol ur bad you lose. The number was " + num + ".");
        }
        
    }
}


If what you want is to check if the value of an input field is equal to another value, and you want to do this as a result of a button being clicked but you want to limit the number of guesses the user can make, you don't need a loop at all. You need a plain if statement that compares the values and also checks that the button has not been pressed more than X times.

More specifically, use an ActionListener on the button to check the condition you want.  Those if statements inside and after the while loop can just be done inside the action listener you already have.

When handling button presses you should handle them inside the action listener of the pressed button, I have made some modifications for your code to make it handle button press properly.
 import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;

public class delete {

    private static int guess = 0;
    private static int presses = 0;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame window = new JFrame("Number Game");
        window.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        JPanel topPanel = new JPanel();
        JPanel bottomPanel = new JPanel();
        JPanel centerPanel = new JPanel();

        JLabel topLabel = new JLabel("Pick numbers from 1 to 77.");
        topPanel.add(topLabel, BorderLayout.NORTH);

        JTextField field = new JTextField(10);
        field.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(80,20));
        topPanel.add(field, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        JLabel bottomLabel = new JLabel("Enter your guess");
        bottomPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        bottomPanel.add(bottomLabel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        //System.out.println(num);

        window.add(topPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        window.add(bottomPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        window.add(centerPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        window.setSize(300,200);
        window.setVisible(true);

        //Generate a random number using the math class
        int num = (int)(77*Math.random())+1;
        System.out.println(num);

        JButton button = new JButton("Guess");
        button.addActionListener(e -> {
            // check the guess only when presses are less than 5 and guess is not empty
            if (presses <= 5) {
                if (field.getText().isEmpty()) {
                    bottomLabel.setText("guess is empty, try again");
                }
                else {
                    guess = Integer.parseInt(field.getText());
                    field.setText("");
                    presses ++;

                    if (guess > num) {
                        bottomLabel.setText("Skill issue, too big. Try again. ");
                    }
                    else if (guess < num){
                        bottomLabel.setText("Ha ha, too small. Try again. ");
                    }
                    else {
                        bottomLabel.setText("GG! You won! You had " + (5 - presses) + " guesses remaining.");
                    }
                }
            }
            else {
                bottomLabel.setText("lol ur bad you lose. The number was " + num + ".");
            }
        });
        button.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100,40));
        centerPanel.add(button, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    }

}

Notes -

variables guesses and presses was doing the same thing, I removed guesses.
I have changed - field.getText() != ""  to - field.getText().isEmpty() 


Before understanding this, prerequisites are:
Basic knowledge of
functions, Java Object Oriented programming;
HI, as you are absolute beginner and do not have prerequisites mentioned above, then please try very simple programs, which do not include GUIs.....
IF You have then lets begin,,,,,,
First of all we will talk about approach..
In GUI based application
the actions are carried out on user's inputs
like a button press, so you have to validate every input on every user press
Yes, you got it right, the main thing is done within the action listener....
But it doesn't mean that you will right all the code within action listener
.. Just break down your code into specific functions
.. call these functions from action listener
Here, I refactored your code a little bit, hence it is not perfectly modular and clean.
but it have the functionality you want, Don't forget to read explanation given below the code .......
package exceptions;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;

public class NumberGame {


    private static int round = 1;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        JFrame window = new JFrame("Number Game");
        window.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        // creating panels
        JPanel topPanel = new JPanel();
        JPanel bottomPanel = new JPanel();
        JPanel centerPanel = new JPanel();


        // adding a top label to top panel
        JLabel topLabel = new JLabel("Pick numbers from 1 to 77.");
        topPanel.add(topLabel, BorderLayout.NORTH);


        // field
        JTextField field = new JTextField(10);
        field.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(80,20));
        topPanel.add(field, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        // button to accept user inputs
        JButton button = new JButton("Guess");

        button.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100,40));
        centerPanel.add(button, BorderLayout.NORTH);

        JLabel bottomLabel = new JLabel("Enter your guess");
        bottomPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        bottomPanel.add(bottomLabel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

-----------------------divider-------------------------------
        button.addActionListener( e -> {
            NumberGame.playGame(field, bottomLabel);
            NumberGame.increaseRound();
        });

-----------------------divider-------------------------------
        window.add(topPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        window.add(bottomPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        window.add(centerPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        window.setSize(300,200);
        window.setVisible(true);
    }

-----------------------divider-------------------------------
    private static void increaseRound() {
        round++;
    }

-----------------------divider-------------------------------
    private static void playGame(JTextField field, JLabel bottomLabel) {
        if (round <= 5){
            int randomNumber = getRandomNumber();
            int guess = Integer.parseInt(field.getText());

            if (guess < randomNumber){
                bottomLabel.setText("Guess is too low. Try Again");
                return;
            } else if (guess > randomNumber){
                bottomLabel.setText("Guess is too high. Try Again");
                return;
            }
        }

        if (round > 5){
            bottomLabel.setText("You lost this game");
        } else {
            bottomLabel.setText("You Won this game!!");
        }
    }

-----------------------divider-------------------------------
    private static int getRandomNumber(){
        return (int)(77*Math.random())+1;
    }
}

Here this functionality shouldn't and couldn't be implemented by while loop..
we call the function playGame every time button is pressed and check for all conditions.
Let us understand each function:
increaseRound and getRandomNumber need no explaination..
function playGame :
it checks whether the round are over or not (is greater than 5)
if round are left (less than or equal to 5) :
generate random number and get the guessed number
if guess doesn't match then display the message and return
// compiler will only reach here when it bypasses the previous if statement
logic to display win or lost message
